# Building backend for reporting using elasticsearch: Is this query possible?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to query elasticsearch to sum the number of minutes an entry is in a given status based on the datetimes for a month?

For example, entries would be of the form:

```
Datetime        Cluster     Hosts_on    Hosts_off   Hosts_on_percentage
Oct 10 12:01    c101        10          2           .8333
Oct 10 12:02    c101        10          2           .8333
Oct 10 12:03    c101        10          2           .8333
```

Is it possible to sum the number of minutes c101 has had greater than 60% hosts based on the datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, but you can get pretty close with something like this:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "Cluster": "c101"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "range": {
                        "Hosts_on_percentage": {
                           "gt": 0.6
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "min_datetime": {
         "min": {
            "field": "Datetime"
         }
      },
      "max_datetime": {
         "max": {
            "field": "Datetime"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

With the data you posted, this query returns:

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "max_datetime": {
         "value": 820980000,
         "value_as_string": "Jan 10 12:03"
      },
      "min_datetime": {
         "value": 820860000,
         "value_as_string": "Jan 10 12:01"
      }
   }
}
```

So then you could calculate the difference in the min and max time client-side.

Or, if you just want a count of the documents returned, you can get it from:

```
"hits": {
   "total": 3,
   "max_score": 0,
   "hits": []
},
```

Here is some code I used to test it (getting the date mapping right is important here):

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/c62289926a18e34b1b1b31e3643f36cbe5a7b4cf

Answer (score 0):

You can definitive sum up minutes if they are in a field for each cluster and datetime. You have to use bucket and metrics aggregation. The condition could be made by a range aggregation.

Links i putted below; i hope i could give you an idea how to solve this task:-)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html